# Eclipse randomly makes changes to my code

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has begun to make random changes to my code in real-time and I have no idea why.
This can start at any moment, lets take today for an example.
I was building a layout for a highscores screen for my app and all of a sudden when I click around my XML code, Eclipse starts removing whole rows of code. I click the deleted row and Eclipse exchanges the code of another row with code from elsewhere in my XML file.

This continues until I restart Eclipse, but start again a few minutes after restart.

Is anyone else experiencing this totaly messed up bug? Is there a solution or should I learn to live with it?

Comment: Sounds like it is the Android Development Tools and not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also seen problems with the Android Eclipse plugin.

Go into Preferences > Android > Editors and try restoring defaults, or unchecking all the auto-anything options.